# Eclipse Scala IDE 4.1.1 - How to run the load project in the interpreter using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, scala

The Eclipse Scala IDE 4.1.1 from Typesafe has a menu option "Window -> Show View -> Interpreter" on which it shows a list of projects available for loading. Once you select the project, it is loaded in the interpreter.

Most of the time I just need to load the current project and play with it in the interpreter, so I need a quick way of doing this, ideally a keyboard shortcut like Ctrl + Alt + S. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The default key combination is `Shift+Ctrl+X`. You can configure another one by going to `Window > Preferences > General > Keys` and then searching for the entry "Send selection to Scala interpreter".